# Consolidate information (time serie) from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

MS SQL Server

I have two tables with different accounts from the same customer:

Table1:

| ID | ACCOUNT | FROM | TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01.10.2019 | 01.12.2019 |
| 1 | A | 01.02.2020 | 09.09.9999 |

and table2:

| ID | ACCOUNT | FROM | TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 01.12.2019 | 01.01.2020 |

As result I want a table that summarize the story of this costumer and shows when he had an active account and when he doesn't.

Result:

| ID | FROM | TO | ACTIV Y/N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.10.2019 | 01.01.2020 | Y |
| 1 | 02.01.2020 | 31.01.2020 | N |
| 1 | 01.02.2020 | 09.09.9999 | Y |

Can someone help me with some ideas how to proceed?

Comment: You want `UNION`.

Comment: if I use UNION, I will get 3 rows. I need the information when the customer was inactive and a consolidation of the timeseries if there´s overlaping between accounts.

Comment: I´m using MS SQL Server

Comment: this is typical gaps and islands problem. If you search online, there are many solutions to this problem

Comment: @VenkataramanR,  I'd say it is easily converted to gaps an islands with a calendar table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the typical gaps and island problem, and it's not usually easy to solve.

You can achieve your goal using this query, I will explain it a little bit.

You can test [on this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3f8a98a5d21a2975b85c0d8f8c641a15).

First of all... I have unified your two tables into one to simplify the query.

```
-- ##table1
select 1 as ID, 'A' as ACCOUNT, convert(date,'2019-10-01') as F, convert(date,'2019-12-01') as T into ##table1
union all
select 1 as ID, 'A' as ACCOUNT, convert(date,'2020-02-01') as F, convert(date,'9999-09-09') as T

-- ##table2
select 1 as ID, 'B' as ACCOUNT, convert(date,'2019-12-01') as F, convert(date,'2020-01-01') as T into ##table2

-- ##table3
select * into ##table3 from ##table1 union all select * from ##table2
```

You can then get your gaps and island using, for example, a query like this.
It combines recursive cte to generate a calendar (`cte_cal`) and `lag` and `lead` operations to get the previous/next record information to build the gaps.

```
with 
cte_cal as (
  select min(F) as D from ##table3 
  union all
  select dateadd(day,1,D) from cte_cal where d < = '2021-01-01'
),
table4 as (
  select t1.ID, t1.ACCOUNT, t1.F, isnull(t2.T, t1.T) as T, lag(t2.F, 1,null) over (order by  t1.F) as SUP
  from ##table3 t1
    left join ##table3 t2
      on t1.T=t2.F
)
select 
  ID,
  case when T = D then F else D end as "FROM",
  isnull(dateadd(day,-1,lead(D,1,null) over (order by D)),'9999-09-09') as "TO",
  case when case when T = D then F else D end = F then 'Y' else 'N' end as "ACTIV Y/N"
from (
  select *
  from cte_cal c 
    cross apply (
      select t.*
      from table4 t
      where t.SUP is null 
        and (
          c.D = t or 
          c.D = dateadd(day,1,t.T)    
        )
      ) t
  union all
  select F, * from table4 where T = '9999-09-09'
  ) p
order by 1
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Dates like `'9999-09-09'` must be treated like exceptions, otherwise I would have to create a calendar until that date, so the query would take long time to resolve.